# Physics transformation energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, energy, kinematics, energy-conservation

A 15kg child slides down a 2.3m -high playground slide. She starts from rest, and her speed at the bottom is 2.1m/s .

What is the change in the thermal energy of the slide and the seat of her pants? (2.s.f.)

I used the kinematics equation

d=[(vi+vf)/2]∗(t)

2.3=2.1⋅t2

t=2.19

Then I used t to find acceleration then multiply acceleration with the mass which is 15kg, and then multiply that again by 2.3m to find the change in thermal energy. But I feel like I calculate t incorrectly, because it keeps telling me it's incorrect. The rest is correct, however, the first part is not correct. I keep getting 30m/s and it is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, t is calculated incorrectly, because d is not 2.3 since the slide is not completely vertical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AT the top of the slide, 
$PE = mgh = 15\times 9.8\times 2.3 = 338.1 J$

Her Kinetic Energy at the bottom of the slide is,
$KE = 0.5mv^2 = 0.5\times 15 \times 2.1^2 = 33.075 J$

The difference must be due to the slide gaining thermal energy.

Thermal energy = 338.1 - 33.075 = 305.025 J